# Read blob from database Android

Tags: android, database

I have a pre-built database, I used SQLiteMan to populate database that contains short stories or articles, so I have a table structure like this:

Table: texts
 id   - integer auto increment
 title - text
 content - blob

The content field contains a paragraph text or strings from a text file I edited from a text editor.

How can I retrieve the contents from the database as text?

Comment: You could always store content as text...

Answer (score 2):

You can get your blob data like this.

```
byte[] byteArray = cursor.getBlob(columnIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you've asked *"as text"* I would clarify the previous answer with:

```
new String(cursor.getBlob(1), "utf-8");
```

of course if you've used a different character set, then you would specify that instead of utf-8.